# Get unique random number in mysql table with a format

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generate a random 4-digit number that is not on the mysql table in database. I used this :

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 9999) AS random FROM table WHERE 'random' NOT IN (SELECT v_code FROM table) LIMIT 1");
if($res->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['random'];
    }
}
```

this is good and generating unique random number but the values in v_code column in my table are with this format: 20171234. It has **2017** as prefix. My question is on how to search a random number in that format? In addition, I would like that random number to have leading zeros. e.g. 0123, 0321, 0432, etc. 
The final number to be search is with this format : e.g. **2017**0123 or **2017**1234 because that is the format in the v_code column in the database table. Please help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with NOT LIKE IN

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 9999) AS random FROM table WHERE 'random' NOT LIKE IN (SELECT v_code & '%' FROM table) LIMIT 1");
if($res->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['random'];
    }
}
```

or a REGEXP might be more efficient

```
 $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 9999) AS random FROM table WHERE 'random' REGEXP (SELECT v_code & '%' FROM table) LIMIT 1");
```